# Autostart remote car starter not working

Tags: subaru, outback, remote-start

The Autostart remote starter is not working.
Everything else works. The unlock door, unlock trunk, lock door all work well. But the remote start doesnt work. I will hear a click when it tries to start the car but then nothing,
Seem like something is missing or disconnected.

Note that usually there's a flashing blue light. Its not the case anymore. There is no more light on the antenna.
I have tested all the fuses in the trunk and underneath the steering wheel and theyre all working.

The car is a subaru outback, if anyone have some tricks i can try,

Thank you,

Comment: Does it start with the key? Check your battery voltage, it could be charged enough to run the auxiliaries but lack the power to spin the starter.

Comment: You are leaving it in neutral or park?

Comment: What year is your Subaru Outback? Also, the remote start had been working before and now is not? Is the vehicle completely locked when you attempt to start it? I mean, are all the doors secure including the rear hatch and engine hood?

Comment: Hi, the car is a 2015 Outback. I've had this remote starter since I bought it in 2015. Its been working fine since then up to recently. Yes the car starts with the key and I leave the car at park. Whenever I try to remote start the car, the car locks up the doors and tries to start the car as I hear some clicking sound. After 2-3 attempts it'll just stop trying. Seems like its behaving normally but something is preventing it. The only thing different I have noticed is that the blue light (antenna) on the windshield is gone. I dont believe its in valet mode either. If anyone have a clue, thanks